# [SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to complete login process due to delay

Tags: sql-server-2012

We have one SQL Server 2012 Fail-over cluster instance where 11 database is running. Application is installed in different server. Application connects from application server to database server. Today application team informed us they got below error and application was  not able to connect database.

> [SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to complete login process due to delay

in opening server connection.

It happened one time only and application could later connect to database. Can anyone please tell me what is the reason behind this error?